# Blackberry - OutOfMemory when handling big images

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Im developing an app that shows big images.. There are a lot of images which size is around 700x8100.. I can create an object of type EncodedImage, without throwing an exception, but when I try to execute getBitmap I receive an OutOfMemory error.
This is the line that occurs the exception:

```
    Bitmap imgBtm = encodedImagePng.getBitmap();
```

Is there any kind of resolution size limit?

Does anyone already had to handle big images?

Any help will be very useful..

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to resize the encoded Image before using the getBitmap() function. First construct your EncodedImage and then rescale it using the following:

```
private static EncodedImage rescaleEncodedImage (EncodedImage image, int width, int height) {
        EncodedImage result = null;
        try {
            int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth());
            int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight());
            int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(width);
            int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(height);
            int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, requiredWidthFixed32);
            int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, requiredHeightFixed32);
            result = image.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        return result;
    }
```

And then after resizing get the Bitmap from it

Answer (score 0):

You can't read images that are so large into device memory.  There are built-in methods to decode an image while scaling it down, which will avoid loading the original image into memory.    Try [EncodedImage.scaleImage32](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html#scaleImage32%28int,%20int%29) to set a more reasonable dimension before getting a bitmap.